# Api hit when i land on previous screen

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

In flutter application when i click on back button last screen comes up and my last screen consists of stateless widget.
I want to refresh the screen's data in that case.

What i am thinking to create a screen state but it will be little complex.

Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create StatefulWidget as an update state when pop screen.

```
final bool? shouldRefresh = await Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
);
if (shouldRefresh ?? false) {
   _refreshData(); // Here is you API call
   setState(() {});
}
```

On your second screen, When the back button is pressed

```
Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
```

Or If you are using system back button than you need to use `WillPopScope` like this.

```
 return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        Navigator.pop(context, true);
        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
       // .... 
      );
```